# Drupal 6 - Shipping quote by country and product weight

Tags: drupal-6, ubercart

I want to setup shipping quotes based on Country and Product weight.
For example:

Country USA = If product weight less than equal to 250 grams then shipping cost is $5
              and for every additional 250 grams it's $3

```
         or 0 - 250 grams shipping cost is $5
            250- 500 grams shipping cost is $8
            500-750 grams shipping cost is $11 ...
```

Country Canada = If product weight less than equal to 250 grams then shipping cost is $4
                  and for every additional 250 grams it's $2

```
         or 0 - 250 grams shipping cost is $4
            250- 500 grams shipping cost is $6
            500-750 grams shipping cost is $8 ...
```

I am using Dupal 6.22 and Ubercart 6.x-2.4

Can anyone please suggest how can I achieve this functionality??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/uc_global_quote

Install and enable the module.

**Edit your store weight unit value to grams at:**
admin/store/settings/store

**Add Canada and USA shipping zones at:**
admin/store/settings/quotes/methods/zones

**Add weight range based quotes at:**
admin/store/settings/quotes/methods/global_quote

In your first example it would be min = 0, max = 250, shipping rate = $5

**Enable the Global quote shipping method at:**
admin/store/settings/quotes/methods

Your site is ready to calculate quotes. Make sure you put in the weights in the product node.